# The web setup wizard does not show up. Instead ..../app/Mage.php not found error occurs on Magento 1.14 install

Tags: magento-1.14

..../app/Mage.php not found

I am trying to install Magento 1.14 sample data on Hyper V machine with CentOS. After all the necessary steps are done, the web setup wizard does not open. Instead, I get ../app/Mage.php not found error.